# Java - How to block a running thread for an exact amount of time?

Tags: java, sleep, game-loop

I need my main Thread to block for a **specific** amount of time. I am currently working on a 2D game and it's pretty laggy just because the *Thread.sleep(2)* sleeps for ~17 seconds and when you move the character, graphics are lagging slightly. Sometimes it's working just fine (when I ran the application about 10 times) and sometimes it's not. I know that there is a delay on the *Thread.sleep(long milliseconds)* method but is there any way to avoid it or an alternative? I already tried *LockSupport.parkNanos((long)2e6)* but that didn't change anything.

Comment: When using `sleep` in a loop on windows, you always must schedule another thread on the background that sleeps forever, else your sleep is inacurate.

Comment: Thread.sleep(2) sleeps for ~17 seconds? There's a huge inaccuracy involved here, but I'm not sure whether to blame the computer or the person using it.

Comment: @Ferrybig Could you provide a citation or reasoning for why the Windows thread scheduler is affected by a background thread always sleeping in this way?

Comment: you're doing something wrong, it would be better if you add some code

Comment: Maybe what you're looking for is a Timer.  You want something that can provide some regularity with its calls.  Take a look at [Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long)).  Just don't schedule it to trigger too frequently or all the time will be spent continually drawing frames.

Comment: I didn't use the Thread.start() or Thread.run() methods because it's my main thread and there are no other Threads running simultaneously, it simply started by running the application.

Comment: @user263980 How much other work you're doing in this thread? How long does that work take? There's your answer.

Comment: @m0skit0 The renderer, the logic processor and the input processor are all running on below 1ms, these are my only processes.

Comment: The guessing game has gone too far already :) Show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the 'game loop' pattern.
This explains it pretty well...
http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php/topic,24220.0

Comment: Thanks, that helped alot!

Answer (score 0):

Your are mentioning graphics, so I assume you are using either Swing of JavaFX. It's generally a bad idea to block a UI thread, as it has to do a lot of work it abstracts away for you.
If you are using Swing, look into [`java.swing.Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html). And make sure you're running in the [event dispatch thread (EDT)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), while you're at it :-).

Comment: Well, Ferrybig's solution did the trick for me so I guess I'll stick to that one. I do not use Swing or JavaFX I am programming with awt. Yea I know it's not recommended but it's fine, I didn't run into serious problems... yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your game to be responsive, you should delegate logic and graphic rendering to different threads. Running everything in one thread makes this application highly unpredictable in matter of calculating Thread.Sleep() effect.

Also please specify what you are using, AWT, Swing, JavaFX? If you use AWT there could be serious problems with rendering smooth animations. I suggest starting with Swing even for very basic games/animations.

As it comes to running threads my favorite is:

1. Creating new Class that implements Runnable with private fileds `Thread thread` and `boolean flag`
2. @Override Run() to have something like 
   `try { while(flag) { refresh(); Thread.sleep(10) } }`
3. In this class create a method startRendering() that sets `flag=true` and starts internal thread `thread = new Thread(this).start()`
4. Create stopRendering() that sets `flag=false`

This allows you to start and stop your animation in your logic thread properly and with ease (without Thread.Abort() and such)

Comment: Thanks for all the effort. I already implemented your idea a little bit different and it's now working. I worked alot with Swing in the past but I don't really like it to be honest that's why i am using awt at the moment. I know it's problematic but I think I can handle that, I am not a beginner ;)

Comment: Thanks for feedback :) Good to hear you have solved your problem.